# NSUUID to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uuid

I need to get deviceUUID from a phone in a NSString format. 
Now I have this:

```
NSString *deviceId = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor;
```

Because what I had before, which was:

```
NSString *deviceId = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;
```

Gives me an error now.

But with the first sentence, I got an alert:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString *' with an expression of type 'NSUUID *'
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As the error tells you, [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) returns an object of class [`NSUUID`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUUID/UUIDString), not a NSString.

If you need a NSString use this:

```
NSUUID *identifierForVendor = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
NSString *deviceId = [identifierForVendor UUIDString];
```

Comment: Thanks for correct me,, i checked with mine code.. and see each time i got diff. deviceID.. can you tell me ? where my code is useful ?

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. It didn't give error with previous version but I saw the edit before testing it. Thank you.

Comment: @iPatel your code is useful if you _need_ different UUIDs. For example when you want to save files to disk and you need unique filenames.

Comment: @iPatel, can you write your code again? I want to keep it for files pourposes.

Answer (score 28):

For anyone looking for how to convert NSUUID to NSString

ObjC

```
NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

Swift

```
NSUUID().UUIDString
```

Swift 3

```
UUID().uuidString
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITE :**
As ***OP's*** requirement I reopen my deleted answer and I mention here **@Matthias's** answer is correct and by using following code you get new device_id each time whenever run this code.

Use following code:

```
CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
NSString *uuidString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL,uuidRef));
CFRelease(uuidRef);
NSLog(@"%@", uuidString);
```

Comment: Should I use those lines instead of mine?

Comment: Just try with my code.. i put this code whenever i need to get deviceUUID in my project.

Comment: @Biribu **No.** This does something completely different. This create a new UUID each time you call it.